# Access violation reading data from binary file into struct in C

Tags: c, struct

I've been trying to read in data from a binary file storing a struct but while the file is read in correctly any attempt to access the struct causes an access violation. 
This is the struct:

```
typedef struct Object {
    const char *Description;
    const char *Tag[20];
    struct Object *Location;
    struct Object *Destination;
} OBJECT;
```

Here's the code used to read in the file:

```
int ReadInDataFiles(OBJECT Objects[])
{
    FILE *pObjectFile = NULL;
    OBJECT TempObjects;

    if (fopen_s(&pObjectFile, OBJECT_FILE, "rb") != 0)
    {
        printf("Error: external file cannot be opened.");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        fread(&TempObjects, sizeof(OBJECT), 1, pObjectFile);

        for (int Count = 0; Count < NUMBER_OF_OBJECTS; Count++)
        {
            Objects[Count] = TempObjects;

            fread(&TempObjects, sizeof(OBJECT), 1, pObjectFile);
        }

        fclose(pObjectFile);
    }
```

Comment: This needs more detail, did you serialize the struct to a binary file? If yes show us the code that does that. Is it possible to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: Don't worry about this, I got carried away trying to get some file handling in it and forgot I created it as a linked list. Should've paid more attention to the rest of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since pointers are assigned in run-time and addresses are handed out in run-time, it makes no sense whatsoever to store/load a binary image containing pointers inside a file, because addresses will vary each time your program is executed.

Therefore you cannot load this struct. You'll have to re-write your whole program from scratch as it makes no sense.